# Calling the Base with Virtual Methods (in Java)

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, overriding

I could have a class called "Item" that has a Property called Name. I could also create a method within "Item" that prints out that "Item's" Name. 
Next, I could create a class called "Software" that extends from "Item." This extended, or inherited class could have the same method that prints the name, except it prints the property of "Software" called ISBN. How do I call upon that overridden method in a manner that lets it run the original method and THEN the overridden method, so that my new "Item," when that method is called upon, prints both the Name and the ISBN of that "Item."

Comment: You could also write a method that does not print out the name but instead returns it as a String. You could then override this method in class Software and call the super method from there to concatenate the names. You could. But you don't have to...

Answer (score 1):

Use the `super` keyword:

```
public String getName() {
    return super.getName() + "(ISBN)";
}
```